# why converting or parsing string to int return zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Why converting / parsing string to int return 0 / zero?

On debug, using the breakpoint, I could see "3" posted to browse action as a string value but when i convert to int as above, the value is converted to 0 value of int type.

```
    //
    // GET: /Event/Browse
    public ActionResult Browse(string category)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(category);


        // Retrieve Category and its Associated Events from database
        var categoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Events").Single(g => g.CategoryId == id);
        return View(categoryModel);
    }
```

Take a look at the image below for better understanding:
[image]

Another image - categoryModel getting null on LINQ query.
[image]

Comment: Well, if the string is `"0"` then converting it to an int should return `0`.  Do you have a specific code sample that indicates otherwise?  Care to share it?

Comment: Okay, this all looks fine.  But the screen shot of the same thing AFTER the execution of TryParse() line would be more helpful.

Comment: Just on a hunch - you realise in the picture above that the breakpoint is on the Int32.TryParse line, ie it hasn't yet been executed, hence id is still at the default of 0. Press F10 (Step Over) and as far as I can tell from the other locals, it should work

Answer (score 5):

From MSDN on Int32.TryParse [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

> When this method returns, contains the
>   32-bit signed integer value equivalent
>   to  the number contained in s, if the
>   conversion succeeded, or **zero if the
>   conversion failed.** The conversion
>   fails if the s parameter is nullptr,
>   is not of the correct format,  or
>   represents a number less than MinValue
>   or greater than MaxValue. This
>   parameter is   passed uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

If your Parse() call fails and your exception is uncaught or you don't test the return value of TryParse(), then surely the int variable would remain as it was - initialized by default to zero.

For example, this would keep your int a zero:

```
int i;
Int32.Parse("FAIL!");
// i is still a zero.
```

So instead try this:

```
int i;
bool parseSuccessful = Int32.TryParse("123", out i);
// parseSuccessful should be true, and i should be 123.
```

Or to see it fail gracefully:

```
int i;
bool parseSuccessful = Int32.TryParse("FAIL!", out i);
// parseSuccessful should be false, and i should be 0.
```

Comment: In your first example C# considers `i` as unassigned and not `0`.

Comment: According to Microsoft here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx it defaults to a zero.

Comment: Btw, unassigneds are not allowed in C#.

Comment: @ Kon - Even when I initiliazed id to zero, i still get the same result.

Comment: You don't need to initialize it to zero (though it may be good practice to do so) - it'll do that by default.

Comment: I have made the Browse action take an int parameter. Now category is getting the right value since the default model binder is doing the low level stuff - "Matt Greer". Presently, the categoryModel object is getting a null from the LINQ query. CategoryId is a primary key in Categories table of the SQL database. I have attached another image for better understanding.

Comment: Strange - If I do something like this via the browser, it works   >>>>> http://localhost:54659/Event/Browse?category=8

Comment: The Browse action in the controller is working perfectly now but the Browse.cshtml view  is not rendered.